# How can I gather data across multiple async sources into a kotlin data class with immutable properties?

Tags: kotlin, reactive

I need to gather data from two or more async sources, massage it a little, then return the result.

```
data class Result(
    var foo1: String?,
    var foo2: Int?,
    var bar1: Boolean?,
    var bar2: List<Boolean>?
)

fun getData(): Single<Result> {

    val res = Result(null, null, null, null)

    return getFoo()
            .map { /* update res.foo1 and res.foo2 */ }
            .flatMap {
                getBar().map { /* update res.foo1 and res.foo2 */ }
            }
}
```

`getFoo()` and `getBar()` have to be called in order because the result of the `foo`s can affect the result of `bar`s.

Since `foo1`, `foo2`, `bar1` and `bar2` should only be initialized once, it feels that there is some way to make them immutable `val`s so that I don't have to worry about accidentally changing them.

I could make an "intermediate" data class for `getFoo()` that only has the `foo` properties, then use it to construct `Result` at the end. But in situations where there are N calls that each update 1-2 properties, it is quite tedious to create N+1 very similar data classes.

Is there any way to avoid creating "intermediate" data classes, while also avoiding usage of mutable class properties?

Answer (score 1):

another approach is to use a builder pattern.
with this approach at each point, you can aggregate your variables until you construct all of them.
then call the build method to create your `Result` data class

```
class ResultBuilder(
    var foo1: String? = "", var foo2: Int? = -1, var bar1: Boolean? = false, var bar2: List<Boolean>? = emptyList()
) {
    fun build(): Result {
        return Result(foo1, foo2, bar1, bar2)
    }
}

suspend fun <V> getFoo(): V {
    TODO()
}

suspend fun <T> getBar(): T {
    TODO()
}

fun getData(): Single<Result> {
    val result = ResultBuilder()
    return result.apply {
        getFoo().map { fooResult ->
            this.foo1 = fooResult.first
            this.foo2 = fooResult.second
        }.flatMap {
            getBar().map { barResult ->
                this.bar1 = barResult.first
                this.bar2 = barResult.second
            }
        }
    }.build()
}
```